# caching of personalized content pages in AEM 6.1

Tags: aem

We are on AEM 6.1 and we have personalized content on the home page of our website based on the user profile attributes. Section of page is personalized using the out of box teaser functionality where we can browse the campaigns. When the home page gets loaded, I believe it makes the ajax call to load the personalized content from campaigns. What i need to confirm is when it loads the page, content is cached in dispatcher, and section of page which comes from campaigns, gets cached in /content/campaigns directory. if this is true then every personalized page will be pulled from cq publisher first time and other times this will be served from dispatcher. So in overall, home page content will be cached in two places. one is /content/homepage(regular content) and personalized content in /content/campaigns in dispatcher. And when home page request comes again, cq will collate the content from above two dispatcher locations and show the final page content on home page.

Can somebody please confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes , the OOTB teaser component loads the campaigns via javascript. Hence the page can be cached and it would still load the right campaigns. If you check the source of a page which has the teaser component , you'll see that  it'll have a call to a function called **initializeTeaserLoader** with details of the campaigns to be displayed in that location and the path to the associated user segments. The campaign to be displayed is then fetched via an ajax call.